# Вывод элементов std::map в отладчике

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

Пользуюсь *gdb*. 

Наблюдаемый субъект имеет имя `m_loginIndexer`.

1. Вывод `print m_loginIndexer._M_t._M_impl`:

(gdb) print m_loginIndexer._M_t._M_impl

```
$20 = {
  <std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<ent::base::CStringUtf8 const, std::unique_ptr<Poker::CInspectedPlayer, std::default_delete<Poker::CInspectedPlayer> > > > >> = {
    <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<ent::base::CStringUtf8 const, std::unique_ptr<Poker::CInspectedPlayer, std::default_delete<Poker::CInspectedPlayer> > > > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
  members of std::_Rb_tree<ent::base::CStringUtf8, std::pair<ent::base::CStringUtf8 const, std::unique_ptr<Poker::CInspectedPlayer, std::default_delete<Poker::CInspectedPlayer> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<ent::base::CStringUtf8 const, std::unique_ptr<Poker::CInspectedPlayer, std::default_delete<Poker::CInspectedPlayer> > > >, std::less<ent::base::CStringUtf8>, std::allocator<std::pair<ent::base::CStringUtf8 const, std::unique_ptr<Poker::CInspectedPlayer, std::default_delete<Poker::CInspectedPlayer> > > > >::_Rb_tree_impl<std::less<ent::base::CStringUtf8>, true>:
  _M_key_compare = {
    <std::binary_function<ent::base::CStringUtf8, ent::base::CStringUtf8, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
  _M_header = {
    _M_color = std::_S_red,
    _M_parent = 0x2316d90,
    _M_left = 0x2316d90,
    _M_right = 0x2316d90
  },
  _M_node_count = 1
}
```

2. Пробую спуститься до первого элемента: (*а в std::map он в данном случае один*): `print m_loginIndexer._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_left`

```
$21 = (std::_Rb_tree_node_base::_Base_ptr) 0x2316d90
```

Далее, рызменовываю данный указатель и получаю следующее:

```
$22 = {
  _M_color = std::_S_black,
  _M_parent = 0xfe94f0,
  _M_left = 0x0,
  _M_right = 0x0
}
```

То есть: как-бэ там ничего и нет. Но один элмент в этом мапе точно есть. Подскажите, в чем дело, или расскажите, как правильно добраться до этого элемента. 
P.S. Случай упрощенный - в мапе **один** элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать так называемый `pretty-printer` для GDB. Как подключать можно посмотреть здесь: [STL Support Tools](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport). После этого STL-контейнеры будут выводиться в удобочитаемом виде.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!